# Create JSON object from dynamic list

Tags: jquery, json

I have a dynamic list and to get each object from each row and convert it into an JSON object that contains an array.
I'm not sure the best approach on how to do this? any examples would be great.

```
<div id="clientList">
    <row id="row_ccf06bc6-75e5-6db5-e7ed-b3f08856fb61">
        <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" id="ClientName_ccf06bc6-75e5-6db5-e7ed-b3f08856fb61">
            <input type="hidden" id="ClientId_ccf06bc6-75e5-6db5-e7ed-b3f08856fb61">
    </row>
    <row id="row_cb5dbc04-62cd-5a19-edf2-2526f7b2aa91">
        <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" id="ClientName_cb5dbc04-62cd-5a19-edf2-2526f7b2aa91">
            <input type="hidden" id="ClientId_cb5dbc04-62cd-5a19-edf2-2526f7b2aa91">
    </row>
</div>
```

```js
var Account = new object();
$.each(row_???
    Account.Clients ='[ClientId: ClientId_???, ClientName: ClientName_???]'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make more sense to have the output as an array of objects, instead of an object with properties containing arrays. With that in mind, you can use `map()` to achieve it:

```js
var arr = $('#clientList row').map(function() {
  var $row = $(this);
  return {
    ClientName: $row.find('input:eq(0)').val(),
    ClientId: $row.find('input:eq(1)').val()
  };
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clientList">
  <row id="row_ccf06bc6-75e5-6db5-e7ed-b3f08856fb61">
    <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="text" id="ClientName_ccf06bc6-75e5-6db5-e7ed-b3f08856fb61" value="Client 1 name" />
      <input type="hidden" id="ClientId_ccf06bc6-75e5-6db5-e7ed-b3f08856fb61"value="Client 1 id" />
    </div>
  </row>
  <row id="row_cb5dbc04-62cd-5a19-edf2-2526f7b2aa91">
    <label class="col-lg-1 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input type="text" id="ClientName_cb5dbc04-62cd-5a19-edf2-2526f7b2aa91" value="Client 2 name" />
      <input type="hidden" id="ClientId_cb5dbc04-62cd-5a19-edf2-2526f7b2aa91" value="Client 2 id"/>
    </div>
  </row>
</div>
```

Note that I used the `:eq()` selector to retrieve the values from the `input` elements. It would be better to put classes on those elements to make selection easier and the code less brittle.

You should also fix your HTML as you're missing a couple of `</div>` tags.